# Atomic update using transaction in firebase android

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to create a simple match making application using android and firebase. 
The working is as follows 
UserA comes online and a node is created on firebase.
UserB comes online and 2nd node is created on firebase. and so on. 
UserA and UserB objects are [image]

Now I want to update UserA with userB fields and userB with UserA fields. 
Ensuring that no other user should interrupt in between this update. like 
[image]

I tried using transaction and found that only single database reference can be changed using transaction. Is there any way by which I can update both user at the same time using transaction and ensuring that both references are either updated or failed at same time.(no in between. like one updated and other is not)

A cloud function can also be used but not know how to use multi path update inside a transaction for real time database.

**EDIT-1**
I have moved to firebase fire store and so far tried below code with firebase functions. Not sure it will server the purpose when user base increases.

```
function matchedUser(xSnapshot, mSnapshot) {

return db.runTransaction(t => {
    console.log(mSnapshot.mUserId)
    console.log(xSnapshot.mUserId)

    console.log("Other Snap ID" + otherSnapshot.mUserId)
    console.log("My Snap ID" + mySnapshot.mUserId)
    const xUserRef = db.collection("Users").doc(otherSnapshot.mUserId)
    return t.get(xUserRef).then(doc => {
      t.update(xUserRef, otherSnapshot)
      const mUserRef = db.collection("Users").doc(mySnapshot.mUserId)
      t.update(mUserRef, mySnapshot)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  })
    .then(result => {
      console.info('Transaction success!')
      return "Success"
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Transaction failure:', err)
      return "Failed"
    })
    }
```

Comment: There are no multi-location transactions in the Firebase Realtime Database. You may be able to use a [multi-location `update()`](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html), as long as the values you're writing don't depend on the existing data. It's hard to be certain whether that's the case without seeing the code of what you tried already.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen take a look at edit.